# Eloquent getting a list of unique patient_id's in an appointment table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a platform with  **Dentists** that have **Appointments** with **Users**

I'm wondering if it's possible to get a list of Patients for this Dentist, based on the Appointment data.

This is my table layout for the Appointments

```
+------------+------------+------------+
| patient_id | dentist_id |    date    |
+------------+------------+------------+
|          1 |          2 | 12/02/2017 |
|          1 |          2 | 13/02/2017 |
|          2 |          2 | 10/02/2017 |
+------------+------------+------------+
```

It could be done with a foreach and filling an array with results and checking unique, but there should be a more elegant way, right?

Even more difficult for me is I should be able to see the date of the last appointment every patient had.

#### Update

The following is working thanks to the code in the answers. But it seems weird to get this in the view?

```
{{ $patient->appointments()->where('dentist_id', Auth::user()->dentist->id)->orderBy('date', 'desc')->first()->date }}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections) to make sure your data is unique.

If your eloquent model relations are set up correctly, you can do something like this:

```
<?php

    $patients = $dentist->appointments()
        ->with('patient')
        ->get()
        ->pluck('patient')
        ->unique('id');
```

The query will load all appointments and corresponding patients. You [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-pluck) the patients out of the collection and make sure all of them have a [unique](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-unique) `id`.

Comment: Amazing! pluck even returns a Model? Didn't know that! Do you know the answer to my bonus question? I'm guessing it's a seperate query?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
SELECT patient_id, MAX(date)
FROM Appointments 
GROUP BY patient_id;
```

Or in Laravel:

```
DB::table("Appointments")
    ->join("user","user.id","=","Appointment.patient_id")
    ->select("user.id")
    ->select("user.name")
    ->select(DB::raw("MAX(date)")
    ->groupBy("user.id, user.name");
```

You can also join by the user table on the patient_id if you want more info like name etc.

Comment: Aha nice! Also working, but this is only returning the max(date) which is perfect! But is it possible to get the other patient data? I tried with ->select('*, ...) but that's not working.

Comment: @Notflip Updated with a join which might work. I think it's probably ideal to translate this to Eloquent but I don't know if there's a straight-forward way to do that.

Comment: Aha working, with a modified version of your answer. I'll add it to my question as well.

Comment: Hmh the issue is, every field I select has to be in the group_by? is that normal?

Comment: @Notflip the SQL standard demands all non-aggregated fields (roughly speaking) to be part of the grouping. MySQL 5.7+ complies with this standard by default. I think laravel has a flag called `strict` in the database configuration. You can set that to `false` if you don't want this to happen.